# How do I slide between two images on mouse over?

Tags: jquery, image, transition

How can I create a section contaiinng 2 images side by side which will expand one of the images to full width when hovering over it. i.e when I hover over the left hand side image the image will expand to the right to display the full image and cover the image that was on the right hand side. Then when I hover over the right hand side image that will expand to the left and cover the left side image.

Examples:

http://www.adhamdannaway.com/

http://www.car-vanstore.cz/

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated, I have been scouring the net for suitable jQuery plugins and CSS tuts but have so far been unsuccessful.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The trick is to understand how to get two images too overlap. I have a working copy of my solution attached.

The method I use relies on absolute positioning. This allows the elements to go over each other. Once this is done I just simply re size my containers and set the overflow to be hidden.

```js
var mouseX;

$("#live-zone").mousemove( function(e) {
   mouseX = e.pageX; 
   mouseX = mouseX+"px";
   $("#x-pos").html("").append(mouseX);
   $("#div-one").css("width",mouseX); 
});
```

```css
img{
    height:525px;/*Only here to ensure that my images are the same height*/
}
#img-one{
    z-index:9999;
}
#div-one{
    width:200px;
    height: 525px;
    overflow:hidden;
    position:absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
    <div id="live-zone">
        <div id="div-one">
            <img id="img-one" src="http://www.asia.ru/images/img/205795/YM-009.jpg">
        </div>
        <div id="div-two">
            <img id="img-two" src="http://www.canadabillard.com/images/thumbs/0000781_600.jpg">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="x-pos">
        200px
    </div>
            
</body>
```

Comment: A similar solution, using drag instead of hover, can be done in pure css, which I find amazing: http://lea.verou.me/2014/07/image-comparison-slider-with-pure-css/

Comment: @Andy +1 but should` mouseX = e.pageX ; mouseX = mouseX+"px";` be 2 separate variables ?

Comment: I just thought it was easier to understand what I was doing. But your right it is unnecessary @AlexanderSolonik

Answer (score 0):

It can be done using only CSS:
HTML

```
<div>
<img src="foo.jpg" class="hover" style="left:1px;background:blue;"/>
<img src="bar.jpg" class="hover" style="right:1px;background:red"/>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
<style>
img.hover{
    position: fixed;
    width: 49%;
    height:40px;
    z-index: 1;
    -webkit-transition: all 500ms cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.250, 0.750, 0.750);
   -moz-transition: all 500ms cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.250, 0.750, 0.750);
     -o-transition: all 500ms cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.250, 0.750, 0.750);
        transition: all 500ms cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.250, 0.750, 0.750); /* linear */

-webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.250, 0.750, 0.750);
   -moz-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.250, 0.750, 0.750);
     -o-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.250, 0.750, 0.750);
        transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.250, 0.750, 0.750); /* linear */
        }

img.hover:hover{
    width: 99%;
    z-index: 100;
}
</style>
```